# sql/sybase varchar length

Tags: sql, sybase

so i was trying to make a code for a document. So if i put 01234567890 and 1234567890 on a table, they should stay there. But when i put 12345667890 and then look the table, that number is different like: 1234566789 (the zero is gone!)

Plus the length must be 11.

If you can help me/understand me, thank you.

```
create table DOCTORS(
    fullname varchar(35) not null,
    document varchar(11) not null,
    salary bigint null,
    homeaddress varchar(35) null, 
    phone bigint not null, 
    cellphone bigint not null,
    speciality varchar(20) not null,
    birthdate date not null,
    gradedate date not null,
    workingdate date not null,
    constraint pk primary key (document) and check(document between '0' and '99999999999'),
    constraint validCellphone  check (cellphone between 3000000000 and 3029999999 or cellphone between 3100000000 and 3129999999 or cellphone between 3150000000 and 3169999999),
    constraint validSpeciality check (speciality in('Medicina general','Ginecologia','Traumatologia','Pediatria')),
    constraint validDates  check (birthdate < gradedate and birthdate < workingdate and gradedate< getdate() and workingdate< getdate() and gradedate<workingdate),
    constraint antiquity check (datediff(dd, gradedate, getdate() )>1461),
    constraint validPhone check(phone between 1000000 and 9999999)
);
GO>
```

Comment: because if you put int, then 01234567890 = 1234567890. And those numbers are totally different for an ID/Document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show the zero at the starting of a number in SQL/Sybase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970337/how-can-i-show-the-zero-at-the-starting-of-a-number-in-sql-sybase)

Answer (score 0):

If you tried `INT` previously,

> 01234567890

is not a number. It's a string.

> 1234567890

is the number.

SQL is able to recognize that those extra zeros are not needed to define the number, so it ignores them. If you want to dispaly a value as 01234567890 to the application, I'd suggest doing the formatting on the application side. That way the number stored in SQL is still a number if you want do addition, aggregation, or other calculations. If you really have to store it as '01234567890', you need to convert it to a character field; `char`, `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `nchar`.