# How can I show the zero at the starting of a number in SQL/Sybase?

Tags: sql, string, sybase

I want to put two totally different numbers like `01234567890` and `1234567890` So I made this code on SQL/Sybase

```
create table DOCTORS(
    document bigint not null ,
);
GO

Insert into DOCTORS values(CONVERT(INT, '01234567890'))

Insert into DOCTORS values(CONVERT(INT, '1234567890'))'
```

But when I do a `select`, it shows me:

```
document
--------
1234567890
----------
1234567890
```

instead of

```
document
--------
01234567890
----------
123456789
```

Comment: If you want leading zeros in the number, perhaps you should consider storing the "document" as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIGINT values represent a spot on the number line.

```
1234567890 = 01234567890 = 1234567890.000
```

To make these values differentiate from each other, they cannot be any sort of a numeric data type.

Strings, however, can make this differentiation.

```
'1234567890' != '01234567890' != '1234567890.000'
```

Make the data type nvarchar(max) to accomplish the differentiation you seek.

Comment: I did that, but I have another problem with nvarchar. If my length is 11 and i put  '222333444555' then it shows me '22233344455'. How can i do to check if the document between  0 and 99999999999? Thank you!

Comment: You're talking about doing a range check, which is a type of [data validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation).  You need to do this before it hits your table.  You could handle this in your front end before you call the insert statement, or you could use (my recommended method) a stored procedure instead of a direct insert, and do your validation within the stored procedure.

Comment: If you want to use an 11-digit number, make sure to convert it explcitily to BIGINT. Otherwise it'll be INT which get truncated at 10 digits (at ~2 billion).